# How to change width of DataGridView Columns

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, width

I have a vb.net windows forms application with a datagridview. I'm hoping to find a way to change the width for multiple columns in a datagridview. This is what I have so far, but it only changes the width for the first column not the rest. I appreciate any help you may give.

```
Dim columnwidth1 As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns(0)
        columnwidth1.Width = 100

Dim columnwidth2 As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns(1)
        columnwidth2.Width = 100

Dim columnwidth3 As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns(2)
        columnwidth3.Width = 100

Dim columnwidth4 As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns(3)
        columnwidth4.Width = 100
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check that you do not have code to change it back (perhaps in the `ColumnWidthChanged` event); and check if `AutoSizeColumnsMode` is on.  Also, you can iterate columns rather than do it individually:

```
For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
    c.Width = 50
Next
```

Comment: You were right, I had autosizemode on by accident. Thanks so much for your help! Happy Coding!